# How to fetch array in layout loop using zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have this in my controller method

```
 $data = array(1,2,3,4,'something');
 Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->assign('whatever', $data);
```

now i want to access this from layout file bu it just give array, how do i fetch array in layout

> echo $this->layout()->whatever;

how do i fetch $data array in layout file ?

Comment: You can't echo arrays. What would you actually like to see displayed instead? Try using var_dump or print_r for debugging.

Comment: In what way would you like to display the information in the array?

Comment: i would display something from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make loop in layout:

```
<?php foreach ($this->layout()->whatever as $item) {
    echo $item;
} ?>
```

Comment: thanks i was just thinking ther is a way around/ shortcut in zf when displaying data from db in such case. Thanks